# What's the term for this type of battery?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, usb

A device I own has this battery:

[image]

I need to replace it, because charging does not work anymore.

Its dimensions are 20mm x 30mm x 4mm.

Its being charged with +5V USB.

What's the term for this type of battery?

Comment: Where did the battery come from?

Comment: Your best bet is to search for spare parts for the original equipment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That battery is a pouch lithium-ion battery.

If he green board contains charging and (very likely and hopefully) protection circuitry, it will be slightly specific to the speed at which the battery can be charged, and how much current the attached circuit wants to draw.

Whether it contains that circuitry depends on how we need to interpret your "charged with 5V" statement: if you mean that the device that this battery was part of is connected to 5V for charging, then most likely, the charging circuitry is elsewhere and this is just lithium battery, and the green board mostly serves connection/soldering purposes.

If you meant that 5V can be directly attached to the leads on this battery for charging, then there needs to be a non-negligible amount of electronics on the backside of the green board, which will manage charging/discharging.

Since there's no markings on the battery, it's impossible to tell you the former capacity of the battery, sadly, or maximum discharge currents.

Comment: It might contain some protection circuitry, but unlikely it does not contain any charging circuitry. The PCB might just connect the wires to battery tabs, so there might not be any protection circuitry, as these may be in the powered device that also contain the charging circuitry.

Comment: well if OP is correct that it's directly charged with 5V, then it has to have some charging circuitry (alternatively, an integrated fire estinguisher)

Comment: I don't interpret it that way that the battery is charged directly with 5V, I interpret that the device has a 5V input for charging. You could say mobile phones are charged with 5V USB as well, which is basically true, but the battery charging circuit is still in the device, between 5V input and battery.

Comment: @Justme I see how you arrive at your conclusion, let me fix my answer.

Comment: These pouch batteries are, at least in my experience, always specifically lithium-polymer batteries; other types of li-ion cells are usually in rigid housings.